# Changing the Color of ComboBox highlighting

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, highlighting

I am trying to work around changing the color of highlighting in a `ComboBox` dropdown on a C# `Windows Forms` application.
I have searched the whole web for an answer, and the best option i found so far was to draw a rectangle of the desired color when the item that is selected is being drawn.

```cs
Class Search
{
    Public Search()
    {
    }

    private void addFilter()
    {
        ComboBox field = new ComboBox();

        field.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Item1", "item2" });
        field.Text = "Item1";
        field.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        field.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        field.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(235, 235, 235);
        field.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        field.DrawItem += field_DrawItem;
    }

    private void field_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;

            if (e.Index == combo.SelectedIndex)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray),
                                         e.Bounds
                                        );
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor),
                                         e.Bounds
                                        );

            e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                                  new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor),
                                  new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
                                 );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code, is that once another Item in the dropdown is selected, the other Item I draw a rectangle is still with the color i want to highlight.
Then i tried to save the last Item drawn and redraw it:

```cs
Class Search
{
    private DrawItemEventArgs lastDrawn;

    Public Search()
    {
        lastDrawn = null;
    }

    private void addFilter()
    {
        ComboBox field = new ComboBox();

        field.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Item1", "item2" });
        field.Text = "Item1";
        field.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        field.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        field.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(235, 235, 235);
        field.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        field.DrawItem += field_DrawItem;
    }

    private void field_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
            if (e.Index == combo.SelectedIndex)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), e.Bounds);
                if(lastDrawn != null)
                    lastDrawn.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor),
                                                 lastDrawn.Bounds
                                                );
                lastDrawn = e;
            }
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor),
                                         e.Bounds
                                        );

            e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                                  new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor),
                                  new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
                                 );
        }
    }
}
```

This line returns an error because of lastDrawn.Bounds (incompatible type)

```cs
lastDrawn.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor),
                                                 lastDrawn.Bounds
                                                );
```

I am feeling that changing the highlight color of the dropdown is impossible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In case you are using the `ComboBox` in more than one place in your project, it will not make sense to repeat the same code for `DrawItem` event over and over again. Just add this class to your project and you will have a new ComboBox control that has the `HightlightColor` property which will makes it easier to use the control all over the project:

```
class AdvancedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    new public System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode DrawMode { get; set; }
    public Color HighlightColor { get; set; }

    public AdvancedComboBox()
    {
        base.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.HighlightColor = Color.Gray;
        this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem);
    }

    void AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0)
            return;

        ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(HighlightColor),
                                     e.Bounds);
        else
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor),
                                     e.Bounds);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                              new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor),
                              new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we use this for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?