# How to change backcolor of combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, backcolor

So I basicly have a textbox, combobox, listbox and button. When I'd like to change the backcolor of the combobox, i'd select the "combobox" in combobox and then choose the option "backcolor" in the listbox. Textbox is for typing the value (for example "red") in and when i'd press the button, the backcolor of the combobox would change to red.

So far I have this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    listBox1.Items.Add("BackColor");
                    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && textBox1.Text=="red")   
                    {   
                        //????
                    }
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Font");
                    listBox1.Items.Add("ForeColor");
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Font style");
                    break;
```

How do I make that happen?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212179/changing-the-color-of-combobox-highlighting there might be some ideas for your case

Comment: @mcy I don't think that code is really for my situation..

Comment: Can anyone atleast give me a hint how to do it? :/

Comment: There just point to writing code like this, use the PropertyGrid control.  If this is homework then you're supposed to figure out by yourself that the if() statement belongs in the button's Click event handler.